# Check an XML file for data items listen in an Excel file and return a listing if there is a match - Code is not working does not find match

Tags: python, xml-parsing

Aloha and Mahalo for assisting me with this issue.
I'm learning to code Python and have my challenges.
What I'm trying to achieve here is the following:

- I have an excel file (xlsx) that has a list of elements that I will be looking for in the XML data file(a list of elements that MUST be in the report file).
  --I need to cehck if each line element appears AT LEAST ONCE in the XML file with an exact match name.
  -- As the result of running the program, I need to create a list where I see elements that can be found in the XML data at least once and what elements that are missing and write/export the results in a new excel file.

Snippet from the excel file:
A9: addrAtDxState
[Snippet from the Excel file used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8FDB.png)

- I have an XML based data file, that has tons lines of data, and each item in the excel file is a line item in the XML database that has a NAACCRID.

Snippet from the XML (actual values are removed):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NaaccrData baseDictionaryUri="" recordType="" timeGenerated="" specificationVersion="" xmlns="">
  <Item naaccrId="recordType"></Item>
  <Item naaccrId="naaccrRecordVersion"></Item>
  <Item naaccrId="registryId"></Item>
  <Patient>
    <Item naaccrId="birthplaceCountry"></Item>
    <Item naaccrId="birthplaceState"></Item>
    <Item naaccrId="causeOfDeath"></Item>
    <Item naaccrId="dateOfBirth"></Item>
    <Item naaccrId="dateOfLastContact"></Item>
    <Item naaccrId="icdRevisionNumber"></Item>
    <Item naaccrId="patientIdNumber"></Item>
    <Item naaccrId="race1"></Item>
    <Item naaccrId="race2"></Item>
    <Item naaccrId="race3"></Item>
    <Item naaccrId="race4"></Item>
    <Item naaccrId="race5"></Item>
    <Item naaccrId="sex"></Item>
    <Item naaccrId="spanishHispanicOrigin"></Item>
    <Item naaccrId="vitalStatus"></Item>
    <Tumor>
      <Item naaccrId="countyAtDxAnalysis"></Item>
      <Item naaccrId="addrAtDxPostalCode"></Item>
      <Item naaccrId="addrAtDxState"></Item>
      <Item naaccrId="ageAtDiagnosis"></Item>
      <Item naaccrId="behaviorCodeIcdO3"></Item>
      <Item naaccrId="casefindingSource"></Item>
      <Item naaccrId="censusTrCertainty2010"></Item>
      <Item naaccrId="censusTrPovertyIndictr"></Item>
      <Item naaccrId="censusTract2000"></Item>
      <Item naaccrId="censusTract2010"></Item>
      <Item naaccrId="censusTract2020"></Item>
      <Item naaccrId="cocAccreditedFlag"></Item>
    </Tumor>
  </Patient>
</NaaccrData>
```

So the program would look for addrAtDxState (taken from the excel file) and check if it appears even once in with a full name match in the XML file.

If yes - add that to the 'Found Rows' worksheet in an output excel file

- if not - add that line item to the 'Not found Rows' in the output excel file.

I tired the following python code, that is partly my creating partly what I could gather from reading the entries on here.

The excel and the xml files are in the same folder as my python file is (I'm using Jupyter for the coding).

The code runs and the comparison is done, but in the export excel file, all elements are in the 'Not Found Rows' worksheet, so it seems that the code does't find any 'matches' from the comparison.

I tried various names in the excel file where I copied 'verbatim' from the XML file (with spaces before the lines), with and without spaces... (if you take a look at the excel snippet uploaded, you will understand what I mean).

I'm out of ideas. I don't undestand why the matching isn't done (even if there is a 1-1 exact line in the excel that shows up the same way in XML) and the code does not recognize if there is a match.

Could it be that the elements in the XML are under  and  element contents? If yes, how do I tell python to 'go an open those up and look inside the  element content'?

Any input/constructive criticism would be appreciated, Mahalo,

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

def read_xml(xml_file):
    tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
    root = tree.getroot()
    data = []
    
    for row in root:
        data_row = {}
        for col in row:
            data_row[col.tag] = col.text
        data.append(data_row)
    
    return data

def read_excel(excel_file):
    df = pd.read_excel(excel_file)
    return df.to_dict(orient='records')

def check_rows_in_xml(xml_data, excel_data):
    results = []
    
    for excel_row in excel_data:
        excel_values = tuple(sorted(excel_row.items()))
        found_in_xml = any(excel_values == tuple(sorted(xml_row.items())) for xml_row in xml_data)
        results.append((excel_row, found_in_xml))
    
    return results

if __name__ == "__main__":
    xml_file = 'Data.xml'
    excel_file = 'List4.xlsx'
    
    xml_data = read_xml(xml_file)
    excel_data = read_excel(excel_file)
    
    results = check_rows_in_xml(xml_data, excel_data)
    
    # Separate the results into found and not found rows
    found_rows = [dict(row) for row, found in results if found]
    not_found_rows = [dict(row) for row, found in results if not found]
    
    # Create a Pandas DataFrame for the found rows
    found_df = pd.DataFrame(found_rows)
    
    # Create a Pandas DataFrame for the not found rows
    not_found_df = pd.DataFrame(not_found_rows)
    
    # Write the DataFrames to an Excel file
    output_excel_file = 'output_results.xlsx'
    with pd.ExcelWriter(output_excel_file) as writer:
        found_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Found Rows', index=False)
        not_found_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Not Found Rows', index=False)
    
    print(f"Results saved to {output_excel_file}")
```

Comment: Please don’t share pictures of data, we will not type your xml file. Share a xml snippet as text instead.

Comment: @Hermann12 Thank you for educating me on this. I've removed the XML pic and added that in as text/code. I wasn't certain about the excel table, so I just left it as is (image snippet). If your time allows, could you take a look at the code and help me figure out what I'm missing here? Mahalo,